# Hypothetical term for existence at every point in time

Tags: word-choice

Assuming that time zero was the big bang and "time" before that did not exist, what is the term to describe something that has existed since "time" began and will continue till "time" ends. I understand that realistically we might never use this term. (Big bang is just a reference, I just wanted to refer to the "beginning of time")

We have terms like *omnipresent* and *omniscient*, for place and knowledge/information, but what about time?

Do *eternal* or *sempiternal* correctly define it? Is there a word like *omnichronos*?

Comment: Did you find the dictionary definition of *eternal* unclear?

Comment: Most of the definitions refer to the word "forever", which has the definition "For all future time; for always". I guess, eternal could fit this meaning. Like I mentioned in the last sentence. I just need confirmation.

Comment: Did you find a word like *omichronos* in any dictionary? Also, if you look up [eternal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eternal) you'll see it means "without beginning or end," so it is not limited to the future.

Comment: Would it be *omnichronos* or *omnichronic*?

Comment: It would be spelled *omnichronous* … if it existed.

Comment: There is room for doubt that eternal fits because it's sometimes defined as *without end*, which does not necessarily mean *without end or beginning*. I think a good answer would demonstrate this particular usage of eternal.

Comment: @z7sgѪ "Eternal" has always conveye not only endless future but also endless past. It derives from Latin *aeviternus*, "of great age".[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eternal "eternal at Online Etymology Dictionary")

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. So far as I'm concerned the jury is still out on the most suitable term, and ELU is a relatively sophisticated adjudicator on such matters. Frankly, I think it's ludicrous to close the question on the grounds OP should have just Googled it. And what? Found "Eternal" really *is* the "right" word? More likely *"Grammar Nazis discovered hiding in ELU"*

Comment: Is this existential question any the inferior to "What's the correct term for the word potato chips?"? [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53873/whats-the-correct-term-for-the-word-potato-chips] I would like this to reopen, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"**[Eternal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eternal)**" means not only endless future but also endless past. It derives from Latin *aeviternus*, "of great age".[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eternal) It is commonly used in this sense. For example, Google [[ eternal father ]](http://www.google.com/search?q=eternal%20father), and you will find that the phrase is often used to mean a supernatural being said to exist for all time. (The Navy and the Mormons are particularly fond of it.)

The other word which pretty well fills the bill for both the past and the future is **"[ageless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ageless)"**.

Comment: **From the dictionary on my computer** ... *Everlasting* refers to something that will continue to exist once it is created, while *eternal* implies that it has always existed and will continue to exist in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I think words like *everlasting* and *eternal* are firmly rooted in the religious framework that primarily associates these qualities with God.

Since OP defines the *"beginning of time"* as the Big Bang, rather than part of the biblical act of creation, I think a "secular/scientific" term might be more appropriate...

> [atemporal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atemporal) - *independent of or unaffected by time, timeless.*

I would say anything which exists independent of time must *de facto* exist throughout all time.

Comment: Or independence of time and existence for all time may be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Though in Medieval theology, "eternal" was understood to mean "existing outside of time", rather than "existing since the beginning of time". It's an important distinction in theological and philosophical discussions.

Comment: That's an interesting point. Is there an online source for this?

Comment: @MetaEd: Several dictionaries I checked list this as one of the definitions. For example, see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eternal, definition #4. Here's a discussion of the concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternity. And here: http://www.beliefnet.com/News/Science-Religion/2004/07/Before-Abraham-Was-I-Am-A-God-Outside-Of-Time.aspx