# What's the correct term for potato chips?

Tags: phrases, synonyms, food

In school I learned to say 'crisps' but I don't want to mix it with french fries. So what's the correct term for potato chips, and what synonyms are there?

Comment: Do you really mean to say "term for the word"? That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: I once ordered Fish and chips in Canada. What I got was fried fish and 'wafers' not French Fries. When asked I was told I should have ordered Fish and French Fries !!!

Comment: The thrust of this question would be clearer if you specified where you want to use the word. I assume that you are asking "What is the correct term [in some specified country or region] for the food item that people in the United States call 'potato chips'?" but without knowing what country or region you want to communicate the idea in, answerers have to guess. By the way, when I lived in Calgary, Alberta, in the early 1970s, a request for "chips and gravy" at a restaurant there yielded a plate of french fries and small dish of thin brown sauce.

Comment: Now I suppose someone will ask what "hash browns" are, and "American fries".

Comment: @hotLicks Well they hasn't in four years! Since I asked this question.

Comment: @svenyargs It was actually a discussion in the chat room for ask ubuntu about four years ago. Where I wanted to know the correct **international** term for *this* item. :) (I think this being a question of what I ate for breakfast...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wikipedia has a nice list of Terms at the beginning of [their article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_chip):

> **Potato chips** (known as **crisps** in British and Hiberno English; either **chips** or **wafers** in Indian English; and **chips** in American, Australian, New Zealand, Canadian, Singapore, South African, and Jamaican English) ...

They chose ***potato chips*** as the article's lemma, which seems to be the least ambiguous term in common use.

Comment: so for a international term that works everywhere is **potato chips** recommended?

Comment: It is if you ask me :) Even though I can't find any good citation or recommendation by anyone authoritative - it seems very sensible.

Comment: Now that chefs are making chips(=French fries) out of beetroot, turnip and other vegetables, *potato chip* in the UK would just mean (US) 'normal French fry', so I fear there is no international term.  BTW, what would the AmE be for a (BrE)turnip chip?

Comment: @Tim: They'd probably be called *turnip French fries.*  You could also call them *turnip fries* or *French-fried turnips,* but the first may be too ambiguous, and I haven't seen the second used, maybe because it's not as appetizing. (I think I've seen *sweet potato fries,* but making chips out of these is quite common here so there is less ambiguity.)

Comment: We do have "French-fried sweet potatoes" around here.

Comment: In the UK, *potato chips* never means the things we call *crisps*. Normally *[potato] chips* are the things you eat hot (with fried battered fish, for example). But sometimes (particularly when *"potato"* is specified) it means those snacky things that come in packets, 4-6 cm long, with 6-8mm square cross-section, made of reconstituted potato powder, air, and oil (I have no idea whether they can meaningfully be said to have been "fried").

Comment: If anything "potato crisp" would be least ambiguous, because it is potato that has been thinly sliced then fried to a crisp. At no point is it ever chipped!

Comment: It should perhaps also be noted that what you normally get when you order fish and chips in the UK are **not** French fries, but (a variation of) Belgian fries. French fries are thinly sliced, whereas the fish and chips ones are usually at least semi-thick.

Comment: @stefanoPalazzo this just got golden! 10k views, on our small diskussion in AU chat. I think someone asked me what I had for breakfast that started this diskussion! :)

Answer (score 12):

In British English, *chips* are deep-fried pieces of potato cut in varying lengths and with a profile that can also vary, but which might roughly be 1cm square. In American English, these are, I understand, called *French fries*, or just *fries*. Very thin deep-fried slices of potato, usually sold in bags and typically eaten as an accompaniment to beer are *crisps* in British English. Elsewhere, I believe they are confusingly called *chips*. So, no, there’s no one term that is internationally reliable. If in doubt, ask to look before you eat or buy.

**EDIT:**

Chips can also be bought frozen to cook in the oven. They're known by the strikingly original name of *oven chips*.

Comment: And there's even, in the same sequence of decreasing flavour, micro-chips, for "cooking" in the microwave.  Alternatively you could eat the cardboard box!

Comment: Wouldn't they be very small ones?

Comment: They should be, shouldn't they.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Chips (British)]

These are potatoes cut into pieces about the width of a finger, and deep fried in lard, beef dripping, or some other fat with similar cooking properties, until the middle is cooked.

In Britain, they are known as "chips".

In the USA they are sometimes known as "chips" (when served as part of "fish and chips"), but they are more frequently called "French fries" - although an American might well complain that these French fries weren't crispy enough.

[image]

These are potatoes cut into narrower pieces, and deep fried in vegetable oil, with the aim of getting a crispy outside.

In Britain they are known as "French fries" on packaging and restaurant menus. Many British people would still call them chips.

In the USA they are known as French fries, or just "fries".

[image]

These are potatoes sliced very thinly, and fried until they are rigid and crispy.

In the UK they are known as "crisps". In Britain, if you asked for "chips" and received crisps, you'd be surprised.

In the US they are known as "potato chips" or sometimes just "chips".

[image]

These are an arbitrary pre-packaged snack that are not made from potato. Although these ones are corn puffs with spicy flavouring, the picture is meant to represent the whole range of crunchy savoury snacks that come in bags.

In the UK, although the packaging will never say "crisps", a person might casually refer to them as "crisps" anyway - knowing it's not strictly accurate, but not caring.

I *think* an American might similarly refer to them as "chips". Perhaps an American can comment and confirm?

Comment: Your last picture is what I'd call "cheese puffs". Though the ones in the picture don't look like they're cheese flavored, at which point I don't know what I'd call them.

Comment: I think this is the best answer as it clearly covers both terms for both items. As for the the bonus bit at the end, we have a great question on this very topic! [Does British English have a word for dry, starchy savoury snacks that are not fried slices of potato?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26374)

Comment: Just to compound things, many US "french fries" are initially boiled in water in a factory, frozen, and then flash-fried in the restaurant.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking as an American: I understand that in British English, "potato chips" refers to wedges of potatos that are fried but still have a soft center. In American English, "potato chips" are very thin sliced and fried to a crisp. What the British call potato chips, Americans call "home fries" or "potato wedges".

I don't know of any term that would mean the same thing on both sides of the Atlantic.

To an American, "french fries" are potatos cut into long, thin strips, traditionally "crinkle cut" but McDonalds introduced straight-cut fries and that has become something of the norm.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. A chip is not typically wedge-shaped, but rather an extruded rectangle.

Comment: Having eaten *fish and chips* in England, I believe English *chips* are indeed American *french fries*. Look at the results of a Google image search for [fish and chips](http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=936&bih=499&q=fish+and+chips&gbv=2&oq=fish+and+chips&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1560l3193l0l3626l14l9l0l0l0l0l273l1348l2.3.3l8l0) and tell me these aren't french fries.

Comment: @Marcin: they're not supposed to be extruded potatoes, at least in the U.S. (and I assume in Britain as well), but cut potatoes. You can't assume that McDonalds serves real french fries (or hamburgers, for that matter). I believe the chips I've eaten in the U.K. were cut.

Comment: @PeterShor - Many Brits use both *chips* and *French fries*. The *skinny fries* you get at fast food places (especially US chains) are often called *French fries* while *chip shops* would normally sell what Americans would call *steak fries* as *chips*. Sometimes pubs and restaurants will offer the choice of *French fries* or *chips*, and if not the type of *chip* an establishment serves can determine whether people choose to eat there or not.

Comment: McDonald's fries in the UK are cut. A few years ago Burger King tried to introduce "stealth fries", which were reconstituted/extruded, but they went down like a lead balloon, and were withdrawn. Shame really - I quite liked them.

Comment: @PeterShor: I mean that the shape is (at least ideally) an extrusion, regardless of the mechanical process by which the chips are manufactured.

Comment: My understanding is that American "french fries" _can be_ thinner [which may be called "shoestring fries", but may also simply be called french fries] than the thinnest that British "chips" can get and that vice versa "chips" _can be_ thicker than the thickest "french fries" [which might be called "steak fries" or (recently in fast food) "natural-cut fries", but might also simply be called french fries], but that there's significant overlap.

Comment: Googling, it looks like McDonalds fries are cut in the U.S. as well, after which they're also treated with preservatives and flavorings, frozen, and sent off to the franchises.

Comment: I'd also note that "crisps" is occasionally used in the US... One famous brand, Pringles are called "crisps" on the label, which may lead some to believe that the word implies they are made of reconstituted potato product.

Comment: But Pringles are not generally referred to as "crisps" in the UK, but as "Pringles": they're too regularly shaped to be crisps.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, brain freeze. I got mixed up. I'd edit my answer to correct it but the discussion has now gone so far that that would just make the thread confusing.

Comment: This is what I mean with "potato chips" http://www.gratissaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/gratis-chips.jpg
the swedish words for this is **chips**...

Comment: "Crinkle cut" is not "traditional" -- the original "french fries" in the US were undoubtedly straight slices, but many restaurants differentiated themselves by "crinkle cutting" them, producing a somewhat crisper texture.  (And of course there are also "crinkle cut" or "ripple" potato chips.)